# While loop not executing C#

Tags: c#, while-loop

```
using System;
using System.Data;


namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool calc1 = false;

            bool end = false;

            double answer = 0.0;

            double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            string op1 = Console.ReadLine();
            double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            if (op1 == "*") ;
            {
                answer = (num1 * num2);
                calc1 = true;
            }

            if (op1 == "/") ;
            {
                answer = (num1 / num2);
                calc1 = true;
            }

            if (op1 == "+") ;
            {
                answer = (num1 + num2);
                calc1 = true;
            }

            if (op1 == "-") ;
            {
                answer = (num1 - num2);
                calc1 = true;
            }



            while (end == false) ;
            {
                string op2 = Console.ReadLine();

                if (op2 == "*") ;
                {
                    double num3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    answer = (answer * num3);
                }

                if (op2 == "/") ;
                {
                    double num3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    answer = (answer / num3);
                }

                if (op2 == "+") ;
                {
                    double num3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    answer = (answer + num3);
                }

                if (op2 == "-") ;
                {
                    double num3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    answer = (answer - num3);
                }

                if (op2 == "=") ;
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(answer);
                    end = true;
                }


            }





        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a multi integer calculator but for some reason, my while loop does not execute so once I enter the first 2 digits and operator, it stops running. Before hand, I had 2 while loops and it would run the second one but it would not print the answer variable when the user entered =.

Comment: let's simplify your issue: the variable `calc1` is useless here, as you assign it, but never use it. (you should have a warning from Visual Studio, btw). Let's remove it from your program.

Comment: second, have you used a debugger? This is an absolute must to learn when you start programming. Set a breakpoint (F9 in Visual Studio) on the first line, then use F10 to "Step-over" each line. You can hover the mouse on variables to check their values, or right click and add to the  "quick watch" list. This will allow you to see what's going one, especially if the execution flow goes into the various blocks. USe the "Immediate window" or the "quick watch" to type expressions to test.

Comment: @Pac0 you are correct about calc1, it is essentially useless with the code OP provided, but I suggest you read into why the loop isn't working, they put a semicolon after the while.

Comment: @crat3us correct (that's why I wrote this as a comment and not in an answer).

Comment: @Pac0 sorry didn't see your answer

Comment: Don't put a `;` after the `while` and `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

your issue is the semicolon `;` after the while condition.

Remove it. (and also all the `;` after the `if` conditions!)

Currently the code is like that:

```
while (condition);
{ you big block of code }  // <--- this is not part of the while loop
```

Because of the semicolon, it's actually the same as

```
while (condition)
    ;

the big block of code // <--- this is not part of the while loop
```

or even:

```
while (condition)
{
}

the big block of code // <--- this is not part of the while loop
```

If you remove the semicolon, then the block is now part of the loop;

```
while (condition)
{
    the big block of code // <--- Now it's like you intended to write!
}
```

This is the same problem with the `if`s, by the way.

If you write a `if (condition);`, that's like `if (condition) { }`, and the other block below will be *always* executed.

Answer (score 1):

You put a semicolon after the while loop, nothing is inside of it.
If you want to have a forever loop, I suggest you use `while(true)`

Edit:
OP, If you wanted to exit the loop at any time, you could simply just do `break;` instead of setting the condition equal to false.